# QML container to split space equidistantly

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I need to put several items in a row (or a column) where all of them will get equal width (or height) equal to `parent.width / number_of_children`. Is there a container which does that automatically?

To simulate that in the WPF you will create a grid with `Grid.ColumnDefinition` declarations with `Width="*"` and just set each child's `Column` property.

How to do that in QML?

Comment: Using `parent.width / number_of_children` is perfectly fine too. Just put the items in a row and you are set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`RowLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    RowLayout {
        width: 200
        height: 32
        spacing: 0
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle {
            color: "salmon"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "navajowhite"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "steelblue"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Setting `Layout.fillWidth: true` will make each item take up as much space as possible, and since each item has it set, they all take up an equal amount of space.

The documentation for `fillWidth` says:

> If this property is true, the item will be as wide as possible while
>   respecting the given constraints. If the property is false, the item
>   will have a fixed width set to the preferred width. The default is
>   false, except for layouts themselves, which default to true.

Comment: I'm aware of that but did not use it because there was something fishy (at least as of Qt 5.6.2) that you should set `Layout.fillWidth: true` only for 1 child. Do you know anything about that or it is my imagination? (otherwise - yes, this is what I need)

Comment: No, I don't remember anything like that.

Comment: I *do* remember it saying that, for what it's worth...

Comment: There is such a rule for the old SplitView, which uses Layout's attached properties: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-splitview.html: "There will always be one (and only one) item in the SplitView that has Layout.fillWidth set to true (or Layout.fillHeight, if orientation is Qt.Vertical)." It's not (and never has been) relevant for Layout types though.